# Setting limitations across has_many through models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, collection-select

Those are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many : memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  belongs_to :group_type
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class GroupType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
end
```

I would like to assign groups to users. there are several types of groups, users can choose only one group from each type. in the view there should a select tag for each group type (a user don't have to be a member of each of the group types).

I can add a type_id column to the membership model and create a instance for each group for each new user, and then update rows, with something like (for type 1):

```
<%= form_for (@user) do |f|
<% @membership = Membership.where (user_id: :@user.id,  group_type: :1) %>
<%= f.collection_select (:membership, :group_id, Group.all.where(type: 1), :id, :name) %>  
<% end %>
```

(not sure that it will work)

anyway I'm sure there is a better way.. how can I connect the models with the one group for each type limitation? (with, ofcourse, a way to edit existing memberships).

I would appriciate any assistance...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model structure look good. You could also include the group_type in the membership and than validate against uniqueness.

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :group_type

  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:group_id, :group_type_id],
message: "can only join one group of this type." }
end
```

The form should create a membership.

```
<%= form_for (Membership.new) do |f|
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %>
  <%# your selection for a group %> 
<% end %>
```

In the controller you have to load the group from the DB, than add the group_type_id to params and .save -> The validation will handle the rest.

Comment: Thank you! I did not understand the last part about the controller. you mean when creating (a membership)?

Comment: when you get the params[:membership] in the controller you have to include the :user_id, :group_id AND the :group_type_id in there. I think from the form you will only get the :user_id and :group_id so you have to find out the :group_type_id by yourself. You could do that in the controller before calling *.save on the model

Comment: sorry, the form creates a new membership - and I guess this means I will have to delete a membership before creating a new one (if both groups are of the same type). am I missing something? I planed that if I enter the form with the user_id his current memeberships will be presented, ready to be changed if need be.

Comment: You could handle all those cases in a before_validation callback in the membership model. So, if a membership with the given category_type is already set, delete it

Comment: Yes, but an existing membership won't be shown in the form- atleast no the one that I have. could you advise on a suitable form, that will present, for each group type, the current group if there is one?

Comment: Puh ! Sorry, I don't think I have time for this :( Maybe you need a bit more than just one select box... maybe two leveled ? Have you tried select2. I think your problem know is also UX related...